# How to do Left join in r

Tags: r

I have two dataset one and two

dataset one

```
a     b  c
111   a  1
112   b  2 
113   c  3
114   d  4
115   e  5
```

dataset two

```
e    d   g
222  ss  11
111  ff  22
113  ww  33 
114  qq  44
234  dd  55
534  vv  66
```

I want to do a left join

Below is the code written in SQL but when i try it in SQLDF it showing as error

```
proc sql;
create table join1 as
select one.*, two.*
from  one left join two
on one.a = two.e;
quit;
```

Answer (score 26, accepted):

With `dplyr`, we can use `left_join`

```
library(dplyr)
left_join(df2, df1, by = c("e"="a"))
```