# merge multi columns in R

Tags: r, tidyr, data-manipulation

I have a sample dataset below and would like to get something like the `Expected Answer`. How can I get around this? Many thanks in advance.

```
name <- c("Michigan Ave & Washington St", "State St & Randolph St", "State St & Van Buren St")
lat <- c(41.88389, 41.88473, 41.87718)
lon <- c(-87.62465, -87.62773, -87.62784)

df1 <- data.frame(name, lat, lon); df1

###
start.name <- c("Michigan Ave & Washington St","State St & Randolph St", "State St & Van Buren St")
end.name <- c("State St & Randolph St", "Michigan Ave & Washington St", "State St & Van Buren St")

df2 <- data.frame(start.name, end.name); df2
```

Expected Answer

```
start.name                     start.lat  start.lon    end.name                      end.lat  end.lon  
Michigan Ave & Washington St  41.88389    -87.62465    State St & Randolph St         41.88473    -87.62773  
State St & Randolph St        41.88473    -87.62773    Michigan Ave & Washington St   41.88389    -87.62465
State St & Van Buren St       41.87718    -87.62784    State St & Van Buren St        41.87718    -87.62784
```

Comment: `merge(df1, df2, by.x = 'name', by.y = 'start.name', all.x = TRUE)`

Comment: You're looking for a left join it seems. Another answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37235759/how-to-do-left-join-in-r